# $p$ being an attracting fixed point of $f$ is equivalent to $p$ being a repelling fixed point of $f^{-1}$

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points, basins-of-attraction

Let $f\colon U\to U$ be a homeomorphism, where $U\subset \mathbb R$ is an open set. By the definition, a fixed point $p\in U$ is attracting if there exists $e > 0$ s.t. if $|x-p| < e$ for some $x\in U$, then $f^n(x)$ tends to $p$. And a fixed point $p$ is repelling if for every $e > 0$ and for every $x$ condition $|x-p| < e$ implies existence of some $k$ such that $|f^k(x)-p| > e$.

My professor stated that $p$ being attracting fixed point for $f^{-1}$ is equivalent to $p$ being repelling for $f$. How can this be proven?

Comment: Your definitions or statement are clearly messed up. What your professor claims is not true, it appears, your are missing some quantifiers on $e$. You might want to confront your question with https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~andrewr/620341/pdfs/fp_sum.pdf